# What is the point of a non-static method in a static class?

Tags: c#, oop, static, scope

I took a look over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179808/what-is-the-point-to-a-static-method-in-a-non-static-class) question and I was wondering the opposite situation. Why would be needed?

Someone said there that:

> Why would you have a "shared method" that is in a class, not in a
>   module? Answer: To share it amongst instances of its class.

Well this it is clear why it would be necessary to use a static method within a non-static class. What about the opposite?

Comment: The original question is about C#. You tagged your question Java. Java doesn't have static top-level classes. Only static inner classes. What's the question exactly?

Comment: Javan and C# are different. In C# you can't have a non-static method in a static class.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite (instance method in static class) is impossible, at least in C#. It produces compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

A class can only be declared `static` when it is a nested class - you do that when you want that nested class to be accessible without having to create an instance of the containing class.

Apart from that, it is just a normal class, which can have an instance state (non static variables) and you would use non static methods in that class like you would in any other class...

For example, [`HashMap` contains a static nested class `Entry` which has some non-static methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry).

ps: you just added the C# tag - my answer relates to your original question, tagged Java.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, static methods work the same way in nested static class as they do in non-nested non-static classes.

In the example given the `main(String[] args)` has to be `static`

If you have a method which doesn't use `this` it is preferable (and simpler) to make the method `static` so its clear the method doesn't need an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Static class cannot be instantiated so there is no use of declaring non static methods inside a static class.